# do not open pop up on session expires

Tags: asp.net

I have a page in asp.net. A button click in the page will open a pop-up.

Now if session is expired, it is opening the pop-up window and in the pop-up it is showing the login screen.

Is there any way in which i can avoid pop-up being opened if the session is expired and directly go back to login page?

Comment: Are you using FormsAuthentication?

Comment: ya it is forms authentication mentioned in web.config

Answer (score 1):

When you say pop-up, do you mean window.open?  If so, then you have to make a AJAX call to verify the session, before opening the new window.

Comment: does an ajax request not extend the session timeout?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your requirement clearly. There is no exact way to achive this. But we can do it javascript.

put a timer(duration would be session timeout, use settimeout function) in the parent page. Check this value before open a popup.